# Running an ARP scan on Raspberry Pi with Python

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, subprocess, arp

I am trying to run an ARP-scan on my raspberry Pi from a Python script.

I have tried the following code using the subprocess library, however when I attempt to print output I receive the error that there is no such variable

```
p = subprocess.Popen(" sudo arp-scan -l", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
status = p.wait()

print(output)
print(err)
```

Is anyone able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: did you `import subprocess`?

Comment: My apologies. Yes I did import subprocess. Thank you

Comment: show your actual error message

Comment: Here is the error message  >>> print(output)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'output' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.run("sudo /usr/sbin/arp-scan -l", shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(p.stdout)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been a bit stupid. I was testing these commands on a Python terminal on my pi and it would not print output. However when I save this as a script and execute it, it works as it should.
Thanks for the help